# Axis2 : four ways to create clients

Tags: apache-axis, axis, axiom

There are 4 ways to create Clients in  Axis 2 as shown

```
1.building an AXIOM based client, 
2.generating a client using Axis2 Databinding Framework (ADB),
3.generating a client using XMLBeans, 
4.and generating a client using JiBX
```

Could anybody please tell me , how can we decide what approach should be used .
please guide me .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. If you are some one who can understand wsdl properly and want more performance. When writing client with AXIOM you get only an AXIOM object and you should know how to get the value from that.

Other methods are data binding techniques

1. ADB gives you better performance and less generated classes. But some of the schema constructs are not available. In other words it is not support xml schema 100% and you won't be able to use it if your schema is too complex.
2. It has almost all schema coverage. But bit slower to ADB and generate a lot of classes.
3. JIBX is used when you have some existing pojo classes.

In addition to this you can use jaxbri as well. Which also similar to ADB and have better schema coverage.

Comment: I want to stick with ADB , so can i use POJO classes when using ADB ?? Please guide me . thank you .